# how to show hierarchy

Tags: website-design, web-app, hierarchy

I Want to Design Hierarchy for Company, let say Under a Company there are different Groups , many Divisions , many Teams , and Many Individuals. 
now i want to design screen/ page which will add More Group,Division,Team...etc. so for that i have designed something is given below:[image]

In given Screen i can Add Group, as i add group he will add Division then so on. and if he want to edit its name its text box he can edit it at any point of time. and if he don't want then he can delete it with cross button.

i think, this design is not good enough to attract use to say wow, is there any fresh design  which will help me. if yes then please share some graphical thing so that i can visualize the data for my application. is it ok if i can add some icon for company, Group, Division, Team.

now i have updated my screen design due to some flow in upper design, its given below:[image]

Comment: Is it important to display the complete hierarchy on one screen ?  Does the structure always be with the 4 same levels  : Group/Division/Team/people or may it vary ?

Comment: yes its important to show complete hierarchy. and yes structure is also same no variations. but i want something fresh to look good. if yes show graphically.

Answer (score 4):

The tree model is more  visual and easier to use than the "folder hierarchy model" (but certainly harder to code)

You can grab inspiration in the genealogy website like [myheritage](http://www.myheritage.com/) but also on some hierarchy builder like [Writemaps](http://writemaps.com/).

Here is a quick mockup, I hope it will help.
[image]

Comment: Definitely a nice look, but the horizontal nature of this really limits the amount that can be displayed.

Comment: Too Much good idea. i am going to follow this 1 only thanks.

Comment: +1 very clean. It's also very adaptable to vertical layout and easy to see available options.

Answer (score 4):

Have the "add new" option within each level of the hierarchy at the place in which it would occur.  This is simpler and removes some ambiguity about where the new element will be created.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPbjeC.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: ohh nice idea. thanks at some extent it may help me, i will try it.